# How to share several desktop areas of one host to different clients

Tags: display, vnc, tightvnc

I'd like to set up the following screen sharing configuration: There are several areas of a screen shared so that each individual viewer (client = "Slave") connects to a different area only (and scales it locally to full screen). On other words: Each shared area of the host (= "Master") computer's screen is displayed on it's individual viewing client (running on a different PC) only.

For example, I want top set up 4 areas on a host system, and 4 clients each connect to a different one of the shared areas in view-only mode, and can see whatever the host moves into those areas. The solution should be easily scalable, so split the host display up into e.g. 9, 12, 16 or 20 or more slave displays.

So, unlike the usual (VNC/TightVNC or similar) sceen sharing, where multiple clients can see the same screen, I want to have each client display an individual area of the host screen only. Also, sharing applications to individual clients or running terminal sessions on the clients won't work - I need the desktop to be split up and shared, so that the same application window can be pushed around and is seen on the client connected to the respective area only.

I had a look for and tried several screen sharing systems, but none seems to allow the above. Did I miss anything ?

Is there any open-source software out there which can provide this functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

The first "solution" that pops up in my head is to setup 4 virtual PC's and let each virtual PC show one broadcast/screen.

Note that this solution is very bad scalable. But since you talk about 4, I think that's ok.

Comment: Not too bad, but the virtual PCs are entirely separate PCs again, so I can't interact between their individual desktops - it would be the same as using Terminal Sessions. Thus the idea of sharing regions of the same desktop, so one Master PC controls what is individually displayed on n clients, and the displayed content can be easily changed. Btw, the 4 slave displays was only an example - my aim would be something like 9, 12, 16 or 20.

Comment: What's the application of your screens? Is it information displays? Lecturing? What is the context of your question?

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific. The primary point is to make something useful of the dozens of 17" LCD VGAs and PCs I have sitting around collecting dust :-)
The idea is to use them in a school project, to set up a video wall. As the equipment would be donated by me, and there is no budget, it has to be a freeware or open source solution. The basic idea is: Teaching how things work, so any solution achieving the above requirements would do.The result then could be used for some status relatively static displays or art installations,up to playing videos or games,depending on the performance.

Comment: @Andy ah. Clear. Maybe setting up one or more pc's with [multiple graphics cards](http://superuser.com/questions/117239/how-can-i-get-multiple-video-cards-to-work-on-linux) is a viable solution? Otherwise, the virtualmachine is still an option, I think, because it's a easy to understand and maintain setup.