# How to find the "Identifier" value for an Xorg conf "Device" graphics card section?

Tags: xorg, xorg.conf

Using `X :2 -configure`, I found out  Xorg was using `Card0` as the device name to configure the graphics driver:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Card0"
    Driver     "radeon"
    Option ....
EndSection
```

I also tried using `Radeon` as the `Identifier` and that worked too. Where does the value of `Card0` come from? In other words, is that a default value for the first graphics card found? And why does `Radeon` also work in its place?

Comment: Use `BusID`, it is unique. [Like in this question.](http://superuser.com/questions/117239/how-can-i-get-multiple-video-cards-to-work-on-linux)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `Identifier` is a name that you give the Device. It is not evaluated by Xorg, it is only used when you want to refer to that Device in any other Section, like Monitor or Screen. For Devices that have no section in `xorg.conf`, Xorg self-assigns names, as you found out, starting with `Card0`. If you had two graphics cards, it would use `Card1` for the second one.